# Ranges and Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function which takes an input of two ranges and one figure. For instance, first range includes the numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and the second range includes [A, B, C, D, E]. If the input figure is then 4.2 - I want the function to first figure out which figure this is closest to in range 1. In this case it is 4, which has a position of 4. I then want to lookup the fourth element in the second range and output that. In this case it should output "D".

I am not sure if I should be converting the ranges to arrays since they are one-dimensional. And I am not sure how to do that and make it work either. Please have a look at the code below.

```
Function getclosest(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal rng2 As Range, tgt As Double) As Double
    Dim position, closest As Double
    t = WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    For Each r In rng
        u = Abs(r - tgt)
        If u < t Then
            t = u
            position = r
        End If
    Next
    closest = Application.Match(position, rng, False)
    getclosest = rng2(closest)
End Function
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What would you expect your function to return in this example?

Comment: I think the function works up until closest = Application.Match(position, rng, False) - But I can't seem to make getclosest return the element of 'closest' this is the issue. I am unsure if this is because I should be converting the ranges to arrays or how to do that.

Comment: Well that doesn't really answer my question, but one problem is that your function is supposed to return a double but you want "D". You could do this with an array formula.

Comment: The Double was all that needed to be changed! thank's a lot. It was driving me crazy.

Comment: Note that this function will fail if `rng` is all negative numbers.  Instead initialize `t` as max possible value: `t = 1.7976931348623E+308`